# UITableView: Run code when tableFooterView is displayed?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm using the UIView *[tableFooterView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/tableFooterView)* of in my UITableView to show a "Loading more" label at the bottom of my table. When the UIView in *tableFooterView* is shown, I need to start some lazy download of content. How do I know when the tableFooterView is displayed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of determining when the footer view will show you **could** check when *the last row of the table is being requested* and load the data then. The number of times a user scrolls to the very last row without scrolling down to see the footer are probably very few. The effect will be the same, i.e. you know when the user has scrolled to the bottom and you should load more data.

This can quite easily be implemented in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. By keeping track of what IndexPath is the last one, and updating it every time new rows are added or deleted, you can simply check if the IndexPath of the requested cell is the same as the IndexPath of the last row and trigger the lazy loading of more data from there, the same way you are currently doing it.

Comment: Voted up because this is how I implemented it once - seems to me the cleanest solution.

Comment: That is exactly what I'm currently doing now. I'll just keep doing it that way.

Comment: I also do the same thing but is this the best way ? 

Answer (score 1):

You can convert footer's frame to window coordinates and compare them. When footer is hidden then it assume that it has Y origin coordinates > 480 (for portrait mode), when footer will appear then Y origin coordinates < 480. You can make comparison in didScroll method.

Thanks, hope this help you.

See method
[convertRect:toView:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/convertRect%3atoView%3a)

Answer (score 0):

Because the tableFooter is, as you say, a UIView it handles the drawing in drawRect: . If you overwrite you may get an notice.

Edit: old answer was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If your `tableFooterView` is observing changes to the table's `contentOffset` property (and perhaps also changes in the table's `contentSize` property), you can calculate exactly when it is scrolled into view with the following variables:

- `tableView.contentOffset.y` - *The vertical amount by which the origin of the content view is offset from the origin of the scroll view*
- `tableView.contentSize.height` - *The height of the content view*
- `tableView.bounds.size.height` - *The height of the table bounds*

If the vertical content offset + the table bounds height exceed the table content size height, we can assume the footer is now in view.

You can wrap this in an if statement and use it to send a notification. You can then do further testing to make the footer dynamically stretch too or other intended effects:

```
if((tableView.contentOffset.y + tableView.bounds.size.height) > tableView.contentSize.height){
    //send notification, dynamic resizing, etc...` 
}
```

Here's a little code snippet in action:

```
// Set up an observer for changes in the table's contentOffset or contentSize.
// This can be done during initialisation of the tableFooterView
[tableView addObserver:self 
            forKeyPath:@"contentOffset" 
               options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
               context:NULL];
[tableView addObserver:self 
            forKeyPath:@"contentSize"
               options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
               context:NULL];

// Further down in code, listen for the changes:
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object 
  change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"contentOffset"] || 
        [keyPath isEqualToString:@"contentSize"]) {

        if((tableView.contentOffset.y + tableView.bounds.size.height) > tableView.contentSize.height){
            // the tableFooterView should now be in view
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
                postNotificationName:@"scrollToLoadNeedsLoad"
                              object:self];
            // dynamically change the footer here (ideal for making it stretch with the table)
        }

    }
}
```

You can implement this inside the view controller that holds reference to a table, or you can encapsulate it inside your own custom ScrollToLoadView.

Comment: Overkill. Triggering a lazy load or whatever you want when the last cell of the tableview is being requested is the way to go.

Answer (score -2):

Simple answer:

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayFooterView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {}
```

Comment: This is called when the _section_ footer view will be displayed; the question was about the `tableFooterView`.