# How do you know when the UITableView is done updating it's view?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

So I implement `UITableViewDataSource` protocol using an `NSFetchedResultsController`.

I then modify the contents of the Core Data base and the `NSFetchedResultsController` then update the tableView..

Is there anyway to know when the tableView has done reloading the data?

We have a complex data model that is caching against a REST implementation, and it's difficult to determine if we need to get more data to fill up the screen (because the screen might be using complex filters against the raw data loaded).   Also, the `UITableViewCell` objects are NOT guaranteed to be the same height.

The easy answer was to simply dump the data to core data, and use an `NSFetchedResultsController` to serve the data to the `UITableView`.

Here is how it works:

- We added a tableview.tableFooterView that displays our "data loading" message.
- Loading up a batch of data from the REST API and then using it update our Core Data objects.
- This triggers the `controllerDidChangeContent` method to trigger, which then triggers a tableView reloadData (eg:)

  ```
  - (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller 
  {
     [self.tableView reloadData];
  }
  ```
- We then basically then "Check" to see if the Footer is still visible 250ms later by calling a method like:

  ```
  [self performSelector:@selector(checkIfFooterViewIsVisible) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.25];

  - (void)checkIfFooterViewIsVisible
  {
    BOOL viewVisible = CGRectIntersectsRect(self.tableView.bounds,self.tableView.tableFooterView.frame);
    if (viewVisible)
    {
      [self getMoreData];
    }
  ```
- We also check to see if the Footer is in view everytime we scroll.

  ```
  - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
  {
      [self checkIfFooterViewIsVisible];
  }
  ```
- If we load the "last batch" of data, we actually just remove the `tableViewFooter` view object from the table (so it can't ever be visible).

So the answer is cool, because we can figure out if we need to pull more data, only if the user "needs" it.  Either because there wasn't much visible data in the first batch, or because they have scrolled down and want more data. Checking the current placement of the `tableFooterView` lets us know if we have "painted" enough data on the screen.

The PROBLEM is - can I get rid of the:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(checkIfFooterViewIsVisible) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.25];
```

If we set the delay too fast, then `UITableView` doesn't have time to update the screen (and change the footer's position).   If we update too slowly, then it feels like the app "stutters" as it loads data, and can load data slower than it could.  But different iOS devices (and different network coverage) are going to mean slightly different timings, so the "let the `UITableView` update and check a bit later" works most of the time, but I feel like this could work smoother.

Is there anyway (maybe by overloading `UITableView`) that we can determine that the `UITableView` is "done" loading `UITableViewCell` objects?  (at least until the next time the scroll moves?).  Adding in this weird delay works well, but it would work cleaner if we knew definitively that the `[tableview reloadDate]` operation has completed.

Comment: You could subclass `UITableView`'s reloadData to trigger a delegate method after.

Comment: I've tried this.  The problem is that reloadData doesn't finish the drawing cycle.  The tableFooterView hasn't always yet changed value.

Comment: Did you try any of the solutions mentioned at http://stackoverflow.com/a/9095292/172690 ?